# Second derivative of a functional defined by an integral

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

> I was reading the following example from the book *Methods in Nonlinear Analysis* (Zhang, Springer) on page 10: First, everything was fine:

Example 2. Let $X = C^1(\overline  \Omega, \mathbb R^N)$, $Y = \mathbb R^1$. Suppose that $g \in  C^2(\overline  \Omega  \times  \mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^1)$.
Define
$$
f(u) 
= 
 \frac 1 2 \int_{\Omega } |\nabla u|^2 
  + 
 \int_\Omega g(x, u(x))
$$
as $u \in  X$. By definition, we have
$$
f'(u) \cdot  \varphi  
 =
  \int_\Omega [\nabla u(x)\nabla \varphi (x) 
   + g'_u(x, u(x))\varphi (x)]dx ,
$$
and
$$
f''(u)(\varphi , \psi) 
 =
\int_\Omega [\nabla \psi(x)\nabla \varphi (x) 
 + 
  g''_{uu}(x, u(x))\varphi (x)\psi(x)]dx .
$$
With some additional growth conditions on $g''_{uu}:$
$$
|g''_{uu}(x, u)| \le  a(1 + |u|^{4/(n-2)} ), 
\ \ \ a>0,\  \forall u \in  \mathbb R^N ,
$$
$f$ is twice differentiable in $H^1_0(\Omega ,\mathbb R^N )$.

> Then, suddenly, I got totally lost:

As an operator from $H^1_0(\Omega ,\mathbb R^N )$ into itself,
\begin{equation}
f''(u) = id + (-\Delta)^{-1} g''_{u}(\cdot , u(\cdot )) .
\end{equation}
is self-adjoint, or equivalently, the operator $-\Delta+g''_{uu}(x, u(x))\cdot\ $ defined on $L^2$
is self-adjoint with domain $H^2 \cap H^1_0(\Omega ,\mathbb R^N )$.

> I just don't understand anything about the second part of the example. For example, where is the $(-\Delta)^{-1}$ in the last equation from? I know it is from integration by parts, but shouldn't $f''(u)$ be an integral?

Please help make it clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that the operator spoken of in the second part is the `Hessian' (the integral disappears because it's part of the inner product). I think this is usually defined by requiring that $f''(u)\phi \psi = (\phi,(\mathrm{Hess}f)(u)\psi)$ for all $\phi$ and $\psi$, where $(.,.)$ is the inner product for the space in which you're working.

Comment: I think the word `Hessian' might be enough to help you out here ;)

Comment: Dear DCM, Thank you so much for your explanation!